# Filemaker html to image conversion

Tags: filemaker

**I have HTML code inside the database but while retrieving HTML code I wants to convert it into image.Their is any plugin which can convert HTML code to image???
Please reply...**

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Web Viewer to render the HTML then take a screenshot of selected coordinates using ScriptMaster's "Screen Capture" module.